# Pandas Dataframe using .loc for assignment gives unexpected results

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing some calculations in pandas and the .loc method is having unexpected results.  not sure if it is me misusing the syntax or a bug.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['series1', 'series2', 'series3'])
df['prev value/unit'] = [99,99,99]
df['value'] = [100,100,100]
df['units'] = [100,100,0]
df['value/unit'] = df['value']/df['units']
```

creates a dataframe where there will be some div  by zero values as shown below.   Business logic dictates that if there is a /0 the prior value/unit should be used.

```
         prev value/unit  value  units  value/unit
series1               99    100    100    1.000000
series2               99    100    100    1.000000
series3               99    100      0         inf
```

so adding:

```
df.loc[df.units == 0, 'value/unit'] = df['prev value/unit']
```

has the desired effect and the inf above gets correctly overwritten by 99 (the previous per unit value).

However if there are no div/0.

```
df.loc[df.units == 0, 'value/unit']
#is a empty Series
#Series([], name: value/unit, dtype: float64)
```

and asigning `df['prev value/unit']` to it overwrites all the values!!!!

so e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['series1', 'series2', 'series3'])
df['prev value/unit'] = [99,99,99]
df['value'] = [100,100,100]
df['units'] = [100,100,100]
df['value/unit'] = df['value']/df['units']
df.loc[df.units == 0, 'value/unit'] = df['prev value/unit']
```

gives:

```
         prev value/unit  value  units  value/unit
series1               99    100    100          99
series2               99    100    100          99
series3               99    100    100          99
```

which is totally unexpected.   Did I accidentally misuse the `.loc` syntax or is this a bug?   I am specifically using the it to avoid assigning to temporary views of the dataframe.   for reference I am using pandas 0.13.1

Comment: This works correctly in 0.14.0; I don't recall the exact issue; give a try and report back.

Comment: have reverted to np.where method proposed by @chrisb in meantime.   will check against 0.14.0 later and get back to you.   So I haven't abused the syntax for change?

Comment: no, the issue was the handling of an empty mask in the row indexer

Comment: confirmed behaviour is different in 0.14.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming it has something to do with views/copies, but it certainly seems like unexpected behavior - you might open an issue on github.

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues

An alternative way to write the code would be using numpy.where, e.g.

```
In [86]: import numpy as np
In [87]: df['value/unit'] = np.where(df['units'] == 0, df['prev value/unit'], df['value']/df['units'])

In [88]: df
Out[87]: 
         prev value/unit  value  units  value/unit
series1               99    100    100           1
series2               99    100    100           1
series3               99    100    100           1
```